# Do I need a dweller in the storage room?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Do I need a dweller in the storage room(s), or can I use the dweller elsewhere?

Answer (score 10):

No, you do **not** need to have a dweller in a Storage Room. You might want to, in case of a fire or radroach invasion, but I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Yeah there doesn't seem to be any benefit other than place to put dwellers if you have no other place to put them.

Comment: The only benefit of having a dweller in a storage room is incase there is an incident. The thing with that though is that there are other dwellers near by so they can just go to the room and take care of it.

Comment: I like to put one in there for aesthetics. I hate the look of the rats in an empty room. :)

Answer (score 4):

Putting a dweller in the storage room keeps them happy. Put high endurance dwellers in the storage room.

Answer (score 0):

The storage room can be working as an empty one. The only reason you want to add dwellers inside is in case of an emergency starting in that spot, so you have people to take care of it.

Adding more dwellers adds NO benefits to your storage.